Question about System`MeijerGDump`*
Steps
Start a fresh kernel, then copy the below sentence, run it.
y2[k_, z_] = 
 System`MeijerGDump`MeijerGToSums[
    MeijerG[{{(1 - k)/2, 2 - k/2, -(k/2)}, {}}, {{0, 
       1/2}, {(1 - k)/2}}, (k - z)/z, 1/2], j] // ReleaseHold // 
  FullSimplify

Then the Context System`MeijerGDump` is automatically imported.
(* It's better to put the below sentence in another input, then run it. *)
?System`MeijerGDump`*

Results
Then it shows
System`MeijerGDump`SlaterForm
System`MeijerGDump`MeijerGInfo
System`MeijerGDump`sortG
System`MeijerGDump`TideUpSummand
etc.

Could you please provide more information about how to use these items, besides the document?

?System`MeijerGDump`* gives Missing["UnknownSymbol"] on a fresh kernel. What do you have to run first?

@ChrisK I've updated the steps in the question description.

PrintDefinitions shows the code. According to the paper, the author found out the internals from developers at WRI. That's two ways to try, if no one in the MSE community can help.

The functions in the System`MeijerGDump`  context are most likely used internally by MeijerG, and are not meant to be used directly by users. The same can be said for any function in a context ending in Private`  or Dump` .  Any use of these functions comes with no support or documentation.
